# Divide HTML table rows into labelled sections

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a valid way to divide a table's rows into sections, with a label identifying that section?

For example, something like the code below, but with a header or caption at the start of each TBODY (Looks like header/captions are only allowed at the top of a table)

```
<THEAD>
<TR> <TH>Weekday</TH> <TH>Date</TH>  <TH>Manager</TH> </TR>
</THEAD>

<TBODY>
<TR> <TD>Monday</TD>    <TD>09/11/2000</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tuesday</TD>   <TD>09/12/2000</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wednesday</TD> <TD>09/13/2000</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thursday</TD>  <TD>09/14/2000</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   </TR>
<TR> <TD>Friday</TD>    <TD>09/15/2000</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   </TR>
<TR> <TD>Saturday</TD>  <TD>09/16/2000</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sunday</TD>    <TD>09/17/2000</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   </TR>
</TBODY>

<TBODY>
<TR> <TD>Monday</TD>    <TD>09/18/2000</TD> <TD>Melody</TD>     </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tuesday</TD>   <TD>09/19/2000</TD> <TD>Christiane</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wednesday</TD> <TD>09/20/2000</TD> <TD>Symphony</TD>   </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thursday</TD>  <TD>09/21/2000</TD> <TD>Starflower</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Friday</TD>    <TD>09/22/2000</TD> <TD>Miko</TD>       </TR>
<TR> <TD>Saturday</TD>  <TD>09/23/2000</TD> <TD>Cleo</TD>       </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sunday</TD>    <TD>09/24/2000</TD> <TD>Alyx</TD>       </TR>
</TBODY>

<TBODY>
<TR> <TD>Monday</TD>    <TD>09/25/2000</TD> <TD>Dancing Star</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tuesday</TD>   <TD>09/26/2000</TD> <TD>Dawn</TD>         </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wednesday</TD> <TD>09/27/2000</TD> <TD>Josh</TD>         </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thursday</TD>  <TD>09/28/2000</TD> <TD>Ryan</TD>         </TR>
<TR> <TD>Friday</TD>    <TD>09/29/2000</TD> <TD>Mary Kay</TD>     </TR>
<TR> <TD>Saturday</TD>  <TD>09/30/2000</TD> <TD>Hallie</TD>       </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sunday</TD>    <TD>10/01/2000</TD> <TD>Paul</TD>         </TR>
</TBODY>

</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My preferred way of doing something like that is to use a `<TH>` that spans (`colspan`) across a full row.

Answer (score 94):

[HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) isn't saying there can be only one `<TBODY>` section. Your code is OK. One more example:

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Fruits</th>
   <th>Vitamin A</th>
   <th>Vitamin C</th>
  </tr>
     </thead>  
 <tbody id="section1">
  <tr>
   <th>Apples</th>
   <td>98 ui</td>
   <td>8.4 mg</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody id="section2">
  <tr>
   <th>Oranges</th>
   <td>295 ui</td>
   <td>69.7 mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Bananas</th>
   <td>76 ui</td>
   <td>10.3 mg</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is a better answer than the one that is currently marked as an answer -- whether or not the <th> spans multiple columns or not

Comment: ...more than one `<tbody>` - never considered this. thank you. this should definitely be the marked answer.

Comment: OP said "with a label identifying that section". I fiddled you code and there is no visual indication that the last two rows belong together. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel You can style your `tbody` elements with CSS or you can also add a `th` element at the beginning of each `tbody` and style that appropriately.

Comment: Regarding labels, what about accessibility?

Answer (score 10):

In response to Alexander Suraphel's question on Martin's answer, yes, the OP wanted to have an identifying label. Here's one way to, combining some of the aspects of several answers, to do that. (Note that I have supplied my own labels, as the OP didn't specify what labels they would have used.)

```css
td {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.grouplabel {
  background: blue;
  color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Fruits</th>
                        <th>Vitamin A</th>
                        <th>Vitamin C</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="section1">
          <tr class="grouplabel"><th colspan="3">Local</th></tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Apples</th>
                        <td>98 ui</td>
                        <td>8.4 mg</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody id="section2">
          <tr class="grouplabel"><th colspan="3">Imported</th></tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Oranges</th>
                        <td>295 ui</td>
                        <td>69.7 mg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Bananas</th>
                        <td>76 ui</td>
                        <td>10.3 mg</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9):

I know, the question is old, but still, I was searching for an answer to this as well. WHATWG has a [great example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element) for the usage of multiply `<tbody>`s with corresponding `<th>`s.

In the case of the question I'd go with:

```css
table {
  min-width: 20rem;
  border-collaps: separate;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

tbody th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-top: .625rem;
}
```

```html
  <TABLE>
    <THEAD>
      <TR>
        <TH id="weekday" scope="col">Weekday</TH>
        <TH scope="col">Date</TH>
        <TH scope="col">Manager</TH>
      </TR>
    </THEAD>
    
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TH scope="rowgroup"  headers="weekday" colspan="3">Week 1</TH>
      </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Monday</TD>    <TD>09/11/2000</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Tuesday</TD>   <TD>09/12/2000</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Wednesday</TD> <TD>09/13/2000</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Thursday</TD>  <TD>09/14/2000</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Friday</TD>    <TD>09/15/2000</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Saturday</TD>  <TD>09/16/2000</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Sunday</TD>    <TD>09/17/2000</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   </TR>
    </TBODY>

    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TH scope="rowgroup"  headers="weekday" colspan="3">Week 2</TH>
      </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Monday</TD>    <TD>09/25/2000</TD> <TD>Dancing Star</TD> </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Tuesday</TD>   <TD>09/26/2000</TD> <TD>Dawn</TD>         </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Wednesday</TD> <TD>09/27/2000</TD> <TD>Josh</TD>         </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Thursday</TD>  <TD>09/28/2000</TD> <TD>Ryan</TD>         </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Friday</TD>    <TD>09/29/2000</TD> <TD>Mary Kay</TD>     </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Saturday</TD>  <TD>09/30/2000</TD> <TD>Hallie</TD>       </TR>
      <TR> <TD>Sunday</TD>    <TD>10/01/2000</TD> <TD>Paul</TD>         </TR>  
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
```

Hopefully, this will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#attr-scope

Comment: Thank you. This should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `colspan` and for some reason if you are not sure how many columns you need to merge/span (dynamically generated columns) then use:

```
<tr><td colspan = "100%">...</td></tr>
```

Comment: A small note on `colspan="100%"`: This is not valid (anymore?). The value of colspan must be a positive natural number between 1 and 1000. See: [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#attr-tdth-colspan).

Answer (score 2):

Generally people use an extra row and use `colspan` to span across all the columns.

In your case: `<tr><td colspan = "7">...</td></tr>`