# JQuery multisortable table rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have table rows as follow :

```
<table id="list" class="sortable">
    <tr class="parent"><td>Item 1</tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 1a</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 1b</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Item 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2a</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2b</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2c</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to Drag n Drop this table > tr using jQuery sortable as follow :

1. `.child` class can only be sorted with other **child class** of **same parent**. ie. between **Item 1a** & **Item 1b**
2. `.parent` class can only be sorted with other **parent class**. ie. between **Item 1** & **Item 2**
3. While sorting/dragging `.parent` class, It's child elements also should be dragged along.

Working Example of my requirement is here : http://jsfiddle.net/3kdSZ/8/

But it has `div's` & siblings.

Is there possibility of achieving similar effect with above `table` Html markup ?

Comment: you have invalid markup. you should have child content of tr wrapped in td elements.

Comment: why dont you wrap the child items in parent tr.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I'm trying to sort WordPress post list table. Wrapping elements in parent breaks the layout completely.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you used the real markup for demo? What is the point of a demo that has no bearing on what you are doing. You can deny a drop BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `tbody` sections which group your `tr`s, then just make them `sortable`

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
  items: "tbody",
  handle: ".parent"
});
$("tbody").sortable({
  items: ".child"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="list" class="sortable">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Item 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 1a</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 1b</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="parent"><td>Item 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2a</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2b</td></tr>
    <tr class="child"><td> - Item 2c</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Related question: [Divide HTML table rows into labelled sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318978/divide-html-table-rows-into-labelled-sections)