# How can you put 'rowspan' specific CSS in an html table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table that uses rowspans:

```css
table tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Section 1</td>
    <td>Data 1a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>Section 2</td>
    <td>Data 2a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2C</td>
  </tr>
```

I'd like to use some simple CSS (like `nth-child`) to be able to add CSS (e.g. background-color in my example) to a specific "Section", which consists of multiple rows.  The number of rows is set by the rowspan.

My example CSS colors the nth table row, whereas I want to color a full rowspans worth of rows.

More specifically, in the example shown, I'd like a way for

- Section 1, Data 1a and Data 1b to be red
- Section 2, Data 2a, Data 2b, and Data 2c to be blue

Any suggestions on an easy HTML/CSS way to do this?  I'm looking for a non-javascript solution if possible.

Comment: Does the css attribute selector work? i.e `td[rowspan]` or `td[rowspan=3]` ?

Comment: @zgood—won't that only select the tds, not the trs? Perhaps put the rows that contain rowspans into a table section?

Comment: @robg Like using a <div> around a set of rows?  Or would that mess up the table (or just not work)?

Comment: @robg - ahhh  do you mean using multiple <tbody>s, like the second answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318978/divide-html-table-rows-into-labelled-sections

Comment: I don't know if I'm perfectly understanding of what you're asking. Are you saying for example that you would just want to color 1a and 1b even though Section 1 and 1a are the same row?

I would say first off that you should have Section 1 and Section 2 as <th> tags instead of normal <td> tags. That way you can you're not targeting them with every <td> if that's the case.

Comment: @JoeL updated question for clarity

Comment: *"[A]n easy HTML/CSS way to do this"* would be to use classes?

Comment: @JoeL—using THs just for styling doesn't fit with their role as semantic markup for headers (poor for accessibility).

Comment: @Brain : Multiple `tbody`s in combination with `tbody + tbody tr` is probably the most flexible solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799672/how-can-you-put-rowspan-specific-css-in-an-html-table/34861243#34861243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that works for me (from @RobG's comment) is dividing the groups rows into sections using `<tbody>`.  Then I can refer to each tbody's nth-child.

Here's the modified example that works:

```css
table tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
tbody:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Section 1</td>
    <td>Data 1a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1b</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>Section 2</td>
    <td>Data 2a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2C</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also work

```css
table tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(3),tr:nth-child(4),tr:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: blue;
}*/
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Section 1</td>
    <td>Data 1a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>Section 2</td>
    <td>Data 2a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2C</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Would work for that fixed case - but every time I added a new row within the table, I'd have to edit all of the CSS numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple classes or ID's for your trs, tds, etc., this is actually a breeze. I added the th's to it but if you make those td's again, it will still produce the same result. By giving each row proper class names, they can easily be targeted and now if you add more `<td>` tags to each red or blue row, they will turn the proper color, as opposed to having to figure out which child is what number.

```css
table tr,
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.red > td, tr.red > th {
  background-color: red;
}
tr.blue > td, tr.blue > th {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="red">
    <th rowspan=2>Section 1</th>
    <td>Data 1a</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Data 1b</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="blue">
    <th rowspan=3>Section 2</th>
    <td>Data 2a</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="blue">
    <td>Data 2b</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="blue">
    <td>Data 2C</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wm0nx4cg/1/

Comment: The problem with this is that it violates the principle of keeping the HTML data and its CSS presentation separate.  So every time I insert a new section, I'd have to adjust the colors in all the other sections.

Comment: @Brian I'm not quite I understand what you mean by this. I admit I'm not an expert on HTML or CSS but when you say "violates the principle of keeping the HTML data and its CSS presentation separate" I'm not sure what you really mean. If you wanted to add a new "Section" you can just give it a new class name. You could even just group one section in a <thead> and `thead {background-color: red}` covers all rows inside the thead tag, and do the same for a tbody tag or tfoot tag.

Comment: Using "nth-child" in CSS, I can set, for example, the first section to blue, second to red, third to green.  It doesn't matter if I move sections around in the HTML or not - they are still always colored in that order.

Comment: I read your response to another answer "Would work for that fixed case - but every time I added a new row within the table, I'd have to edit all of the CSS numbers."  
In this jfiddle, I added a 3rd section https://jsfiddle.net/fc9m1etp/1/ and if you ever add another row within the section, the row will be the color you need it to be and colspan need to be +1 so the rows fall into place. But you said you don't want to make manual edits.
So what I would like to know is how are rows of data being generated? How often do rows need to be added? Without those answers, idk why my method fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make any changes to your HTML, this is probably the simplest solution :

```css
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

tr, tr + tr  {
    background-color: red;
}

tr + tr + tr {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Section 1</td>
        <td>Data 1a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>Section 2</td>
        <td>Data 2a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 2C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2f58jtq5/).

---

If you're willing to consider adding `tbody` elements to your code, then consider this alternative :

```css
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

tr  {
    background-color: red;
}

tbody + tbody tr {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2>Section 1</td>
            <td>Data 1a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1b</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=3>Section 2</td>
            <td>Data 2a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 2b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 2C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2f58jtq5/1/).